# remove element from the array of AR object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is a dropdown menu which contains an array of AR objects.
Need to show the element if the amount in the cart more than 3000.

I do so

```
element_of_dropmenu.delete_if {|x| x.name == "free delivery" && basket_sum < 3000} # remove one element
```

The amount in the cart is not true for the DeliveryType. This is a different model

you can do so

```
if sum > 3000
  element_of_dropmenu
else
 element_of_dropmenu.drop(1)
end
```

I need to display all elements when the `sum>30`, and remove one element when `sum<30`

i use **rails 3.2.6** and **ruby 2.0.0** :)

I think the way to do it wrong and ugly.
Tell me how to correct the code in a better way.
Thanks.

Comment: You can use `where` method, or in your `element_of_dropmenu` or creating a new variable. If you post how do you set your `element_of_dropmenu` will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve the result with simple SQL or ActiveRecord methods. Sth like below snippet would solve your problem.

```
YourModel.where(["name = ?  AND basket_sum < ? ", "freedelivery", 3000])
```

or,

```
YourModel.where("name = ?", "freedelivery").where("basket_sum < ?", 3000)
```

Comment: The amount in the cart is not true for the DeliveryType. This is a different model. i update question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call mutator methods on ActiveRecord from 4.1 onwards check [release notes](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#active-record-notable-changes)

> Relation no longer has mutator methods like #map! and #delete_if. Convert to an Array by calling #to_a before using these methods.

You can make use of `select`

```
element_of_dropmenu.select {|x| x.name != "free delivery" && basket_sum > 3000}
```

Or as `marmeladze` suggested you can use where clause or better create a scope

```
scope :premium, -> { where("name = ? AND basket_sum > ?", "free delivery", 3000) }
```

And chain it with association

```
element_of_dropmenu.premium
```

Comment: i use rails 3.2.6 and ruby 2.0.0 :)

Comment: Then it should work but still you can try you luck with this